How can I eliminate spaces around Panel titles in Rich?
I'm using Rich's Panel feature. Is there a way to eliminate the extra spaces Panel puts around title text? Here's an example from a Wordle program, which shows a sequence of Guesses. (It is written in and runs in Colab, hence the use of Rich.)

The spaces before and after the title text are intentional. (They are part of the title text.) It's the spaces between those spaces and the Panel outline that I'd like to eliminate.
Thanks.

Why not trim the title text when you want to have spaces anyway?

I added the extra spaces hoping they would over-write the empty space. But that didn't work. No matter the title text, there are empty spaces between it and the Panel outline.

You say that the spaces before and after the title text are intentionally. But you also say, that there are spaces before and after the title text you don't want to have? That doesn't make any sense. Please [edit] your question to be more clear if you want to want spaces or not (or what exactly you want instead).

Please look more closely at the image. To the left/right of the title text there are spaces over a dark background. (The same dark background as the rest of the image.) These spaces are part of the title text and would disappear if taken out of the title text.
In addition, to the left/right of those spaces are spaces over a gray background. (You can see that same gray background at all four edges of the image.) It those spaces over the gray background that I'd like to but can't eliminate.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem when executed. When I run a quick test with the examples on https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panel.html I don't get any additional spaces. Maybe there are some color settings which are affected by this.

Would you mind posting your code and result. I'd like to see what you do to avoid the extra spaces.

I have used the examples from the homepage like this: https://ibb.co/Pzbxt1H and they look like expected. However, I'm not using any complex color scheme like you have in your application. That's why you should add a MCVE to the question of the problem you have, which also shows how you have setup the colors and have setup the panels (and labels and other stuff).

Here is a colab page with code extracted from the larger system.  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wZ9oGcXvhQeRBi-lw3XxTXIePcXssM9W?usp=sharing (Probably spent more time on it than it's worth!)

Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Sorry, It's too long to include in a question. Please look at the code itself.

That's why you should add a minimal reproducible example. Remove any code that is not related to the problem. Links to external sites are useless when the link target gets deleted.

Your example shows spaces around the title even though the code does not include spaces at the ends of the title text. From your example, it appears that the extra spaces are built into how Panels are displayed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

From the image that @progman posted (https://ibb.co/Pzbxt1H), it appears that the spaces I want to eliminate are built into how Panels are displayed. I would like the white space around the title text to be the same color as the Panel background. That seems not to be possible.

